# Annotate photos using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, photo

I want to annotate photos for an iOS App, i was searching if any library exist that would help me set the base.

Basically i am looking to implement similar functionality like skitch app : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap.-mark-up.-send./id490505997?mt=8

The feature i am working on requires the user of application to capture a picture, highlight specific area of the picture and comment on it.

Any leads on how to go about it is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this library, its for signatures, but those are basically annotations anyway. https://github.com/jharwig/PPSSignatureView

Comment: Thanks, let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco Arment, the creator of BugShot, open sourced BugShotKit to let developers add support for annotation easily. You can have a look at the project here https://github.com/marcoarment/BugshotKit

Comment: This is excellent, unfortunately the developer does not want it used in app store build "Please do not ship it in App Store builds."

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar You can extract out the portions you want, and make it App Store safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , i hope this will help you

```
 #pragma mark touches stuff...

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView]; // This is your view

       }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        currentTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];

        CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context,10);

     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor brownColor].CGColor);
                CGContextSetBlendMode(context,kCGBlendModeDarken );



        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through all the packages used by SkitchSnap and these is the basic libraries you should take a look at: 
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities
https://github.com/coryalder/UIImage_Resize

They also have a lot of other libraries that you should look in to.
Example: To get the gray effect, user-login, converting SVG objects, testing..

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense that they are using SVG image and scale it, this is very helpful, I am wondering how could you possibly get to know about the packages used in an app?

Comment: They have to include the licenses.
Go to Settings->Legal and you will find them all. There is some work to find the code because they often just use the name of the software and the developer. Example: GHUnit by Gabriel Handford, iRate by Nick Lockwood on 26/01/2011 etc.